# Fractional scaling not working on 19.04

Tags: xorg, display-resolution, hdpi

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 19.04. I have 2 monitors, one with a resolution of `3840x2160` and another with a resolution of `2560x1440`. I have enabled `x11-randr-fractional-scaling` using dconf.

The fractional percentages show in Settings, however when I try to set my 4k monitor to anything above 100%, it automatically goes to 200%. If I change the percentage on the `2560x1440` monitor, it will scale correctly, however it will also force the unmodified 4k monitor to scale to 200%.

How do I get the 4k monitor to scale to 1.25-1.5x and keep the second monitor the same scale?

Comment: Fractional scaling still is an experimental feature. May probably need some patience before it works as expected in all situations.